# Iframe com atributo src recebendo um link da internet

Tags: php, javascript, html

Estou criando um iframe em uma página, e no atributo src, quando defino um link qualquer (com http://...), ele simplesmente não abre.

Por exemplo:

```
<iframe src="http://www.google.com"></iframe>
```

Isso abre só o contorno da caixa do iframe sem absolutamente nada dentro, parecendo que não aceita links no SRC... Como posso fazer isso?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Há sites que de facto não podem ser mostrados dentro de iframes. Isso é porque esses sites têm "ligado" uma opção de segurança chamada [`X-Frame-Options`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/X-Frame-Options).

Esse [`X-Frame-Options`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/X-Frame-Options) é um header (pode dizer-se que é um dos parâmetros de configuração),  e diz ao Browser se ele está ou não autorizado a mostrar o conteúdo desse site em casos que a iframe e o site de origem estajam a correr em dominios diferentes.

A [defenição oficial da entidade reguladora (RFC7034)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7034) é :

> To improve the protection of web applications against *clickjacking*,
> this document describes the `X-Frame-Options` HTTP header field, which
> declares a policy, communicated from the server to the client
> browser, regarding whether the browser may display the transmitted
> content in frames that are part of other web pages.

Eu traduziria assim:

> Para melhorar a protecção das aplicações web contra o *clickjacking* ,
> o documento informa o cabeçalho HTTP `X-Frame-Options`, que
> declara uma política ou regra, comunicada do servidor para o cliente, sobre se o navegador pode exibir o conteúdo em elementos `<frame>`, `<iframe>` ou `<object>` inseridos em outras páginas da web.

Comment: Excelente resposta! Obrigado!

Comment: @Programmer de nada. Se quiseres podes marcar a resposta como aceite.